# Import 24-words Ledger mnemonic into Metamask

Tags: metamask, ledger-nano-s, mnemonic

Given a 24-word mnemonic from Ledger HW wallet, is it possible to generate the corresponding 12-word mnemonic for Metamask?

In other words, if I have a wallet on Ledger, can I import it to Metamask (so that I can see balances, make transactions etc, without connecting the Ledger)?

Comment: This would completely defeat the purpose of a hardware wallet... why do you need that ? for convenience ?

Comment: You should not do that. If connecting Ledger to Metamask is not working for you, here is the official support https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

Comment: @hroussille yes